# Supabase RLS to check the 'users' table's 'owner' column using auth.uid() but it returns syntax error

Tags: supabase

```
CREATE POLICY "Allow admin access to test table." 
ON test FOR ALL TO auth.uid()
WHERE
  (
    SELECT
      ADMIN
    FROM
      users
    WHERE
      users.owner = auth.uid() //auth.uid() = users.owner <--- tried this too
  );
```

This causes

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: CREATE POLICY "Allow admin access to z_test table." ON z_test FOR ALL TO auth.uid ()
```

How can I allow users to do all when 'users' table's column 'onwers' return TRUE?

Comment: The role comes after the `TO` keyword. In your case, you probably want to apply the RLS policy to `authenticated` role. You can read the RLS docs here to learn more about the syntax and some sample code: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#policies